# restriction of cohomology classes to pseudoconvex domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $U\subset X$ be a relatively compact strongly pseudoconvex open subset (not Stein) in a complex manifold.
Are there general results (always zero, injective, surjective...) on the restriction $$H^1(X,\mathcal F)\rightarrow H^1(U,\mathcal F_{|U})$$
for $\mathcal F$ a vector bundle on $X$? (or even just $\mathcal F=\mathcal O_X$).